# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes/lags when launching apps other than terminal

Tags: 20.04, gnome, crash

I am using Dell XPS 13 and, just yesterday, upgraded from 16.04 to 20.04. Everything seemed to work fine yesterday, but things got weird today.

Whenever I open an app other than the shell terminal, nothing opens and lags---the mouse moves around, but the cursor is stuck at the loading icon, and nothing is clickable. No keyboard inputs work either. Terminal can be opened and run commands, but closing it by pressing "x" buttom triggers the same issue. Right-clicking on Desktop or pressing the "super key" to open search menu works, but doing so while having the terminal open triggers the same issue.

I have tried most search results that seemed remotely similar, including turning gnome extensions off via gnome-tweaks, resetting /swapfile, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. In particular, I'd like approaches via terminal, since I can't seem to open/run most other things.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you open your terminal and type "gedit". This is the text editor runs with your display server. Copy the error messages and add them to your question. BTW-on your login screen you could select `X-server` or `Wayland`. Try `X-Server`

Comment: How exactly did you attempt to upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04?  Before upgrading, did you disable or remove software that isn't in Ubuntu repositories?  Is there software that you used in 16.04 that isn't compatible with 20.04?  Because you mentioned gnome-tweaks, I'm assuming that you have made changes to your system that aren't typically allowed under system settings- are you sure those changes are compatible with 20.04?

Comment: @kanehekil gedit opens, but closing it (via x button or alt f4) triggers the issue. See edited post for other info.

Comment: Can you append your question with the output of `free -h`